# Why is the GPU grayed out?

Tags: gpu

Here is the very elaborate, confusing, even befuddling image which I have selected at the time of this strange error occurring.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNjzD.png

Comment: GPU stands for Graphics Processing Unit. It's probably because you don't have an in-built graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow Blender to use your graphics card.

Go to Edit->Preferences->System and select the card you want to use.
If there’s nothing there, you don’t have a compatible graphics card.
No worries, CPU rendering works too.

[image]

Happy Blendering.